# Which one is better, using View.OnClickListener or View Binding to code setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know how to use **ViewBinding** to get the **Button** View object on Android Studio. But, I am curious about the best way to code **setOnclickListerner** on my Android App. In my case, I wrote my Kotlin code as below:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            binding.btnCameraCTA.setOnClickListener(this::openCamera)
            binding.btnHeroesCTA.setOnClickListener(this::openHeroesApp)
            binding.btnMoviesCTA.setOnClickListener(this::openMoviesApp)
        }
    
        private fun openCamera(view: View?) {
            val isCameraFeatureExist = checkCamera()
            if (isCameraFeatureExist) {
                val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivity(takePictureIntent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(view?.context, "Your device doesn't have any camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    
        private fun checkCamera(): Boolean {
            return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)
        }
    
        private fun openHeroesApp(view: View?) {
            val heroesIntent = Intent(view?.context, HeroesActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(heroesIntent)
        }
    
        private fun openMoviesApp(view: View?) {
            val moviesIntent = Intent(view?.context, MoviesActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(moviesIntent)
        }
    }
```

But, we also can write those codes using **View.OnClickListener** with **when expression** as below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    
        binding.btnCameraCTA.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.btnHeroesCTA.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.btnMoviesCTA.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun checkCamera(): Boolean {
        return packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.btnCameraCTA -> {
                val isCameraFeatureExist = checkCamera()
                if (isCameraFeatureExist) {
                    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                    startActivity(takePictureIntent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Your device doesn't have any camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            R.id.btnHeroesCTA -> {
                val heroesIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, HeroesActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(heroesIntent)
            }

            R.id.btnMoviesCTA -> {
                val moviesIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MoviesActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(moviesIntent)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody tell me which one is the better way? and why is that? Thank you

Comment: You should check this place out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117338/how-to-use-view-binding-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There is no big differences between these two. In fact they both implement `View.OnClickListener` interface. In your first code, take this for example:

```
binding.btnCameraCTA.setOnClickListener(this::openCamera)
```

`View.OnClickListener` interface has `setOnClickListener` method which gets `v: View?` as input and returns `Unit`. As your `this::openCamera` method has exact same input and output as `setOnClickListener` method, you can use it instead of an object that implements it.

It means deciding to use which one, will be based on your own preferences and code styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think using separate functions is more appropriate in terms of code readability. I prefer the first one. Besides, using MVVM pattern and two-way data binding will reduce your code complexity.
You may want to look at the links below in order.

Good Luck!

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way