# Assigning a TextView Array to a string in a single command

Tags: arrays, android-studio

Recently, I have been trying to make a simple calculator program in Android Studio using Kotlin.
The program uses two inputs (a,b) and gives four outputs (p=a*b, q=a/b, r=a+b, s=a-b).

The outputs are TextViews with ids out1, out2, out3, out4, which are read together as an array called res, see line1. Simple calculations are performed and the results (p, q, r, s) are assigned to res, see lines 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
// Line1:
val res = arrayOf(findViewById<TextView>(R.id.out1), findViewById<TextView>(R.id.out2)     findViewById<TextView>(R.id.out3), findViewById<TextView>(R.id.out4))

// Lines 2, 3, 4, 5:
res[0].text = String.format("%.2f", p)
res[1].text = String.format("%.2f", q)
res[2].text = String.format("%.2f", r)
res[3].text = String.format("%.2f", s)
```

---

Is there a simpler way to write these lines? For example,

```
// Line6:
val res = arrayOf(findViewById<TextView>(R.id.[out1, out2, out3, out4]))

// Line7:
res.text = String.format("%.2f", [p, q, r, s])
```

I tried the simpler way, i.e. Line 6 and 7, but it throws me an error.
For Line 6, it says "The expression cannot be a selector (occur after a dot)"
For Line 7, it says "Unresolved reference: text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to achieve is not possible since that's not how arrays work.

I will suggest you to take a look at [viewBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58549401/21365487) which is a very easier and quicker way to access views in activity class.

After this you'll simply be able to do like below

```
binding.out1.text = "Your text 1"
binding.out2.text = "Your text 2"
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but this keeps code simple.